# DatePicker crash in samsung with android 5.0

Tags: android, exception, android-5.0-lollipop, samsung-mobile, android-datepicker

I am having trouble with creating a datepicker in samsung note 2 device with lollipop 5.0.
The exception is:

```
java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: %d can not format java.lang.String arguments
    at java.util.Formatter.badArgumentType(Formatter.java:1489)
    at java.util.Formatter.transformFromInteger(Formatter.java:1689)
    at java.util.Formatter.transform(Formatter.java:1461)
    at java.util.Formatter.doFormat(Formatter.java:1081)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1042)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1011)
    at java.lang.String.format(String.java:1803)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:1457)
    at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:397)
    at android.widget.SimpleMonthView$MonthViewTouchHelper.getItemDescription(SimpleMonthView.java:684)
    at android.widget.SimpleMonthView$MonthViewTouchHelper.onPopulateNodeForVirtualView(SimpleMonthView.java:628)
    at com.android.internal.widget.ExploreByTouchHelper.createNodeForChild(ExploreByTouchHelper.java:377)
    at com.android.internal.widget.ExploreByTouchHelper.createNode(ExploreByTouchHelper.java:316)
    at com.android.internal.widget.ExploreByTouchHelper.access$100(ExploreByTouchHelper.java:50)
    at com.android.internal.widget.ExploreByTouchHelper$ExploreByTouchNodeProvider.createAccessibilityNodeInfo(ExploreByTouchHelper.java:711)
    at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfVirtualNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1179)
    at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1091)
    at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1087)
    at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1087)
    at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1087)
    at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1087)
    at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1087)
    at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1087)
    at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1087)
    at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1087)
    at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1087)
    at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchAccessibilityNodeInfos(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:888)
    at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.findAccessibilityNodeInfoByAccessibilityIdUiThread(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:155)
    at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.access$400(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:53)
    at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$PrivateHandler.handleMessage(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1236)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5944)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
```

I have used the example provided in the official android studio page:

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
            implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it

        DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this,year, month, day);
        return dpd;


    }
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // get the date here

    }
}
```

I call it like this:

```
DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
```

In other devices works fine.

I also tried creating my own layout with a `DatePicker` in it, really simple but also crashes. Is this some Android bug?

Comment: It's a bug in Samsung's version of Lollipop that is not present in AOSP. You will need to contact Samsung support.

Comment: I though the proguard cfg solved it but it's still crashing. The problem was in the style Theme.AppCompat for Samsung Note3 only. My resolution was to change the style of DatePicker `DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),R.style.MyDatePicker, this, year, month, day);`

Comment: Hi @vilson could you explain R.style.MyDatePicker a bit more? What did you put in there? Thanks!

Comment: @AlexBlack     `<style name="MyDatePicker" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:background">#AAAAAA</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/Title_text_12dp</item>
    </style>   <style name="Title_text_12dp" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
    </style>` it was crashing because the activity had the style `Theme.AppCompat`

Comment: Hmm, when I use that my datepicker looks very different, like a broken version of an old style.  I'm thinking i might try an IF statement and only use that style on crashing devices somehow?

Comment: Would using new DatePickerDialog(getAcitivity(), android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault, ...) work?

Comment: @AlexBlack tried it but its still crashing, it displays the DatePicker and then crashes

Comment: Thanks for trying. Did you find any to keep its appearance the same (esp on lollipop) and still avoid the crash

Comment: I posted a new possible approach for a solution, would be great to get feedback if it works: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34853067/348378

Answer (score 3):

As Ridcully says, its an issue with Samsung's 5.0 implementation

Workaround suggestions can be found here. Unfortunately none are the most pretty.

[DatePicker crashes on my device when clicked (with personal app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28618405/datepicker-crashes-on-my-device-when-clicked-with-personal-app)

Answer (score 1):

Forget about the built-in date picker. There's only one way to get rid of the crash: use a library that provides an independent implementation.

For a date picker fragment: https://github.com/flavienlaurent/datetimepicker

For a date picker widget: https://github.com/SingleCycleKing/CustomTimePicker (this is more a starting point than a ready-to-use-solution)

Comment: How can you be sure that third party library wouldn't crash?

Comment: I've tested both libraries on a device where the build-in date picker crashed. Plus I released my apps using the libs and suddenly the crash reports stopped. This is not an exact proof, but I didn't receive any crashes caused by the libraries itself. Well, there's never a guarantee that open source libs will be free of bugs ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As alanv noticed, this is a bug of Samsung's Android 5 implementation.

I set up a different theme which shows the date picker with the (older) spinners instead of the calendar view. In the code, I check if the app is running on a samsung device with lollipop and a language other then english, and if so, I apply the theme with the spinners. This works well and there are no other libraries or other hacks necessary.

If needed I can add the theme and how to apply it to this answer.