# Application Crashes When Showing DatePickerDialog

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I'm using the following code to show DatePickerDialog in onClick method. And when user choses the date I set it in a textview. The error is occuring on 5 line where DatePickerDialog is being called. I've tried debugging it, the error is on the exact line and I'm unable to figure it out.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.startDate_et) {
        final java.util.Calendar c = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(java.util.Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                     startDateEt.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);
                }
        }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        datePickerDialog.show();
}
```

But when the method is called application crashes with following message.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.bisma.calendar_analyzer, PID: 3882
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Binary XML file 
line #20: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:112)
at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:82)
at com.example.bisma.calendar_analyzer.ui.CreateEventActivity.onClick(CreateEventActivity.java:100)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:112) 
at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:82) 
at com.example.bisma.calendar_analyzer.ui.CreateEventActivity.onClick(CreateEventActivity.java:100) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:112) 
at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:82) 
at com.example.bisma.calendar_analyzer.ui.CreateEventActivity.onClick(CreateEventActivity.java:100) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/color/mcv_text_date_dark.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0c006c
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2640)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
at android.widget.DatePickerCalendarDelegate.<init>(DatePickerCalendarDelegate.java:155)
at android.widget.DatePicker.createCalendarUIDelegate(DatePicker.java:160)
at android.widget.DatePicker.<init>(DatePicker.java:140)
at android.widget.DatePicker.<init>(DatePicker.java:126)
at android.widget.DatePicker.<init>(DatePicker.java:122)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:112) 
at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:82) 
at com.example.bisma.calendar_analyzer.ui.CreateEventActivity.onClick(CreateEventActivity.java:100) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #7: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(StateListDrawable.java:182)
at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:115)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1215)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1124)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2630)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540) 
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870) 
at android.widget.DatePickerCalendarDelegate.<init>(DatePickerCalendarDelegate.java:155) 
at android.widget.DatePicker.createCalendarUIDelegate(DatePicker.java:160) 
at android.widget.DatePicker.<init>(DatePicker.java:140) 
at android.widget.DatePicker.<init>(DatePicker.java:126) 
at android.widget.DatePicker.<init>(DatePicker.java:122) 
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:112) 
at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:82) 
at com.example.bisma.calendar_analyzer.ui.CreateEventActivity.onClick(CreateEventActivity.java:100) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
```

Here is the complete XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="16dp"
tools:context="com.example.bisma.calendar_analyzer.ui.CreateEventActivity">


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/eventTitle_et"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:hint="Event Title" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/description_et"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/eventTitle_et"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:hint="Description" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/startDate_et"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/description_et"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_field"
    android:hint="Start Date/Time"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textColorHint="@color/white" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/endDate_et"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/startDate_et"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_field"
    android:hint="End Date/Time"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textColorHint="@color/white" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/create_event_btn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/endDate_et"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Create Event" />
```

Comment: show your xml please

Comment: There is no issue with XML(I'm updating the question anyway) .... when I do something else in onClick it works fine. and there is no XML for DatePickerDialog

Comment: please update complete xml

Comment: check the update @vishaljangid

Comment: Please update your class and post whole code of from where you are calling date picker.

Comment: please check the update @Maddy

Answer (score 0):

1. This is the java class file

   TextView startDateEt;

   ```
                   @Override
                   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                       startDateEt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.startDate_et);
                       startDateEt.setOnClickListener(this);  
       }     
               @Override
                   public void onClick(View view) {
                       if (view.getId() == R.id.startDate_et) {
                           final java.util.Calendar c = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
                           int mYear = c.get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR);
                           int mMonth = c.get(java.util.Calendar.MONTH);
                           int mDay = c.get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                           DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                                   new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                                       @Override
                                       public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                                           startDateEt.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);
                                       }
                                   }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                           datePickerDialog.show();
                       }
                   }
   ```
2. This is xml file

```
    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/eventTitle_et"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:hint="Event Title" />

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/description_et"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/eventTitle_et"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:hint="Description" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/startDate_et"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/description_et"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:hint="Start Date/Time"
            android:padding="10dp"

           />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/endDate_et"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/startDate_et"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:hint="End Date/Time"
            android:padding="10dp"
            />

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/create_event_btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/endDate_et"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Create Event" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I've tried the exact same code in another project and it works just fine

Comment: it is the first thing in question sir

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but for the benefit of anyone coming here from Google:

I was getting this exact InflateException (line # and everything) on my API 21 emulator but not my API 26 emulator. trying some things from the answers on [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28618405/datepicker-crashes-on-my-device-when-clicked-with-personal-app) led me to setting the title on the DatePickerDialog, which stopped it from crashing

```
    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                 startDateEt.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);
            }
    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    datePickerDialog.setTitle(""); //ADDED THIS LINE
    datePickerDialog.show();
```